# How to make a UV of the outside of a model?

Tags: texturing, uv

How could I make it so that I have a UV map that is the outside of a model? For example, I could place two cubes, but one displaced both vertically and horizontally. I group them together, and make a uv map for it. This would cause some of the UV to be inside of the displaced cube, instead of the image smoothly transferring between cubes.

Edit: I have added a very rough drawing to show what I was trying to say. The two cubes connected, having different UVs, would make an added texture likely clip through the connected model. It might be easier to think of it like a shadow, hovering over multiple different objects.   [image: rough drawing of two cubes connected.]

Comment: Hello, I have trouble visualizing what you're trying to do, would you mind adding a screenshot or a mockup to your question ?